# Converting full path of Image to binary

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, binary

firstly, yes I know it might be a duplicate question, but really, I have applied all possible answers but nothing worked.

What I want is to convert an image selected by the user to binary format, and I'm using asp.net/c# to do such method. 
Look at my codes first to do this:

```
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            pressNumberOfTimes++;
            string strname = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
            lbl_homeCarouselAdd.ID = "lbl_homeCarouselAdd" + pressNumberOfTimes;
            strDiv.Append(string.Format(strname) + ",");
            FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/upload/") + strname);
            string fullImagePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/upload/") + strname;

            byte[] imgdata = File.ReadAllBytes(fullImagePath);

            var a = String.Join(",", lbl_homeCarouselAdd.Text += strDiv.ToString());
```

from what I have seen from the answers in this website and others to convert image to binary is to use this code:

```
byte[] imgdata = File.ReadAllBytes(fullImagePath);
```

which I have used in my codes. 
However, all I get is an empty value for the binary, while "fullImagePath" variable holds the full bath of the selected image.

I have also used the following method, but it gave me the same empty result:

```
  public static byte[] ImageToBinary(string _path)
    {
        FileStream fS = new FileStream(_path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        byte[] b = new byte[fS.Length];
        fS.Read(b, 0, (int)fS.Length);
        fS.Close();
        return b;
    }
```

**For more info:**
This is how my web form looks like

[image]

so, the user can upload an image and then click "save image" button in order to save the selected event, and here the website should convert the image to binary format.

**Concerns:**

1. Is it possible that "upload" folder in my "VS" project is not refreshed with the new selected image is the reason behind the empty value??
2. Is it possible that permissions among c:\ directory is causing such error?? because I'm working on a machine given by the company I work for, and I did face some issues before regarding this.

Comment: check ~/upload/ folder is available in your project or system where you are targeting to upload.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that API but, are you making sure the user file is totally uploaded before trying to open it?

Comment: yes it is available

Comment: _"all I get is an empty value for the binary"_ - what does this mean _exactly_ and how did you determine that? You don't seem to be doing anything with the `imgdata` variable afterwards.

Comment: I didn't really get what you mean, but yes the image is uploaded and actually i'm not trying to open/show it. I just want the file name of the selected image to be converted to binary in order to save it in my database.

Comment: I tested your snippet. It saves the file in the upload folder and I get the data in `imgdata`. Are you sure the file is written in the upload folder?

Comment: @user3599431 when multiple people respond, use `@username` in your comment to respond to a particular user. What I meant is that your problem is unclear. You're claiming _"all I get is an empty value for the binary"_, and it is unclear what you mean by that exactly. Do you mean `imgdata` is an empty array?

Comment: Also, what does _"I just want the file name of the selected image to be converted to binary in order to save it in my database"_ mean? Why do you need to convert a file **name** to binary in order to save it in a database? Anyway `File.ReadAllBytes()` is not going to give you the file _name_, but its contents.

Comment: @CodeCaster I mean the imgdata is empty .. and i want it to be saved as binary in database because a mobile application will use the database to display images

Comment: @VDWWD  yes, the image is saved to upload folder. Did you get the binary format for selected image in `imgdata`?

Comment: Yes I did get the file as binary data.

Comment: @VDWWD that is weird .. I don't know why it doesn't work for me! Could it be because that the "upload" folder in my vs project is not refreshed with the new selected image??

Comment: @VDWWD another concern, could it be because of privileges/permissions among c:\ ?? because I'm working with a laptop given from the company I work for, and faced some issues before because of permissions.

Comment: I don't think so, if you could not read/write the file you'll get an Exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(FileUpload1.HasFile)
{
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);  
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(filename);  
            string contentType = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType;  
            HttpPostedFile file = FileUpload1.PostedFile;  
            byte[] imgdata= new byte[file.ContentLength];  
            file.InputStream.Read(imgdata, 0, file.ContentLength);  
}
```

Comment: I get empty result in `imgdata `